# Why might a struct store its own size?

Tags: c++, winapi, sizeof

I am taking my first look into the Windows API and upon encountering [**WNDCLASSX**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I couldn't help wondering why its member, **cbSize**, existed. The description of **cbSize**, per the MSDN is: *The size, in bytes, of this structure. Set this member to sizeof(WNDCLASSEX). Be sure to set this member before calling the GetClassInfoEx function.* This describes it, and hints at its purpose, but I don't undestand the necessity.

My question is this: Why would a struct ever need to store its own size? Wouldn't any function handling the struct have access to that information using [**sizeof**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

Comment: My guess: convince. Also efficiency, it is much more efficient to run sizeof( something ) once and store it, then use it over and over again, than it is to run sizeof over and over.

Comment: `do_something_with((struct foo*)i_am_a_bar_ptr);`

Comment: Version-assist and machine platform are two common reasons.

Comment: @DanielFischer *Excellent* var-name =P

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain wouldn't sizeof( ) be resolved at compile time (and hence take zero processing time)?

Comment: *"Wouldn't any function handling the struct have access to that information using sizeof?"* - Not if it's just given by a pointer to some *"base class"* struct.

Comment: TheFloatingBrain, Sellorio, if you look at the disassembly, assignment of the structure size requires a single assembly instruction since the size is known at compile time, it just has to populate the member variable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Later versions of the Windows API may add new fields to the struct. If the struct has a size, then older code can call the API function, which only copies the fields that the old code is aware of.

Comment: Muscles answered it correctly.

Some additional reasoning.  They might've used a version member where a version 2 of a structure was later used.  By using the sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) for the cbSize member instead, it allows the structure to automatically be scaled up (or down theoretically) when later versions come along without changing source code.

When I was new to the Windows API I wondered the same thing.